# Multivariate Bell polynomials

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, probability-distributions

[Bell polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials) are very useful, amongst other things, for obtaining moments of some polynomial type generating functions. For example, using the expression

$$ \exp \left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^n/n! \right) 
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty B_n[a_1,\ldots,a_n] x^n/n! ~,$$

for some polynomial type generating functions 
$\sim \exp(a_1 x+ a_2x^2/2 + \ldots)$ one can immediately get moments.
Above, $B_n$ are complete Bell polynomials.

I want to look at a more general case where we are no longer in 1D, 
i.e. promoting $x$ to a vector $\textbf x$, I could write something like

$$ \exp \left( x_i V_i + \tfrac{1}{2} x_j x_k T_{jk} + \ldots \right)
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} x_{i_1}\ldots x_{i_n} 
\textbf B_{i_1 \ldots i_n} \big[ \textbf V, \textbf T, \ldots \big], $$

where $\textbf V$ is a vector, $\textbf T$ is a matrix, etc.
Is there some general theory (recursion relation, properties, etc.) similar to 
Bell polynomials for 1D case that would describe these $\textbf B_{i_1 \ldots i_n}$ tensors?
Any good reference would be much appreciated!

P.S. I found some papers by Withers&Nadarajah that looked somewhat relevant from abstract, but anyhow I don't have access to those.